# How to make URL case insensitive with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am using Nginx for a simple demo website, and I just configure the Nginx like this:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     www.abc.com;

    location / {
        index           index.html;
        root            /home/www.abc.com/;
    }
}
```

In my `www.abc.com` folder, I have sub-folder named `Sub`, and inside has `index.html` file. So when I try to visit `www.abc.com/Sub/index.html`, then it works fine. If I visit `www.abc.com/sub/index.html`, it returns `404`.

How to configure the Nginx to case-insensitive in URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement Nginx case-insensitive directory-location redirection 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587354/how-to-implement-nginx-case-insensitive-directory-location-redirection-301)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
server {
    # Default, you don't need this!
    #listen          80;

    server_name     www.abc.com;

    # Index and root are global configurations for the whole server.
    index           index.html;
    root            /home/www.abc.com/;

    location / {
        location ~* ^/sub/ {
            # The tilde and asterisks ensure that this location will
            # be matched case insensitive. nginx does not support
            # setting absolutely everything to be case insensitive.
            # The reason is easy, it's costly in terms of performance.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above solution in not working for me..Can you please help me.~* works only for if condition

Comment: I think this will match all urls *containing* /sub/ (e.g. it would also match "example.com/yellow/sub/").  It should be `location ~* ^/sub/` (with the caret).

Comment: Not working for me too. May be I implemented it wrong.

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xyz.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
        location / {
                root    /home/abc;
                location ~* ^/sub/ {
        }
    }
}