# how to get php server variable case sensitively in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, header

I am unable to get php server variable in case sentive manner. all are converting into upper cases.

In My example client will send custom headers like `X-campaign-Name`. i have to receive same and send it back to client in json format with same case.

But in php all are converting into upper case not able to determine user case to respond back.

Let me know anyway i can access the headers in same case of user is sending. I am ok to install any third party addons on php or nginx to make it work.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415508/how-to-make-url-case-insensitive-with-nginx

Comment: Thanks for reply. i does not help