# How to rewrite all URLs accessing my site (nginx server) to lowercase?

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, case-insensitive

I've just noticed that my content is available both on

```
http://domain.com/page
http://domain.com/PAGE
```

(and many other-cased variations).

How can I set nginx to 301 redirect all incoming requests to their lowercase equivalents?

I did some googling and all I could find was people using perl scripts inside nginx from 2013.  It's late 2016 now and I feel this is a very simple/basic/desired feature that nginx must have added, but I'm failing to find an answer.

For the time being I have this in my PHP instead:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($uri !== mb_strtolower($uri)) {
    Header ('Location: '.mb_strtolower($uri), true, 301);
}
```

Which does the job (though I expect I'll come across somme "gotchas" at some point).  But it only addresses anything that goes through PHP, so I can't use it (for example) to redirect `.JPG` requests to the correct `.jpg` extension.

Comment: This appears to be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415508/how-to-make-url-case-insensitive-with-nginx

Comment: I don't think it is unfortunately, there's nothing in there about how to redirect to the correctly- (lower-) cased version.

Comment: Is that not essentially the equivalent of having a case-insensitive location? It sounds like you want Nginx to direct /PAGE and /page to the same resource which would be asking for case insensitivity on your location. You could do some rewrite rule but that seems overkill

Comment: But I want to do it for every single request to the domain, what you're suggesting would have me type out every uri my site has...

Comment: @Codemonkey can you post the solution for your problem in case it is resolved? I am having a similar issue and not able to figure out the nginx location config.